# PC reverting to infected state after virus removal

Tags: virus

Whenever I leave my PC with a technician to get rid of viruses, this happens; at the shop the technician demonstrates that all has been fixed, but when I return home and connect hardware, after 15-20 minutes all would reset to previous infected state!

Is there a possibility of a hardware virus(es)?

Comment: A lot of variable parameters that can change the conclusion. With the current information you gave us, it will be pure speculation.

Comment: Yes, hardware viruses are possible. No, the chance you'll get infected with this sort of virus is extremely low. These are pretty costly and aim at specific hardware; not something that'll get wasted on the Jon Does of this world.

Comment: It might also be that your [router is infected](https://www.google.com/search?q=router+infected). In this case every time you come back home with the clean PC and use your router you will be infected again within a short time because the router will redirect you to malware.

Comment: How does the router infect actually a pc,just connecting to config.-page?

Comment: Also what software did they use to get rid of the virus?  Maybe they didn't get it all.  Did they reformat the whole computer and start over fresh?  That is really the only way to be certain.  DBAN before the re-install to make sure it isn't hiding in used or special areas of the hdd.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, much like a car mechanic couldn't diagnose a problem without actually seeing it but here's what I can say.

Remember that your computer is only 1 of many devices on your network.  There's at least 1 more computer on your network, and that's your router.  You may not know it, but it's a computer running an operating system, and is capable of being infected.  There could be a bad firmware on the router, or it could be something simple like changing the DNS settings to redirect your web traffic to compromised IP addresses (DNS determines which IP to contact when you for example type in http://stackexchange.com).

I recommend you update your router if it's out of date, and reset to factory defaults, and reconfigure it.

You may also have external devices such as an external hard drive, a camera, or a cellphone which you connect to your computer, which may be infected.

Do you have a smartphone?  Do you connect it to your wireless network?  Have you ever installed an app outside of the Google Play store?

Do you have a printer?  Printers are notoriously insecure, and if they're exposed to the internet (some are), they're easy to find and compromise.

There's so many possibilities I really can't give you a solid answer, but I hope this can help you narrow down the issue.  Your first step is probably to determine which 'virus' you're dealing with.  What is the virus identified as.

Lastly this website is for security discussions, we can't be everyone's tech support, so I can't just walk you through how to fix this, but if you have specific questions, that may help other people in the future, feel free to post them.  Just make sure it's in a clear, concise manner, and you've done some of of your own research first.

Comment: In fact there are a wifi-adapter, two mices,a keyboard and also a printer and almost forget a usb-hdd.It's silly but do I have to replace them all?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but it's unlikely the keyboard,l or mice have any issues (at least I've never heard of those being compromised).  The usb hdd though would be my first suspect by far. Try to scan it for viruses using a linux live cd. If you don't know how, google it. There's a lot of examples.